# how to upgrade mysql (innodb) version in xampp under linux OS

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp, manjaro

i'm using xampp 7.1.8-0 on my "manjaro linux" machine, mysql (innodb) version is 5.6.36-82.1 and l have problems with this version and wanna upgrade to 5.7 version so any suggesions please?!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to reintall higher version on xampp , that would be much easier if package upgrade is not an option,[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAKvz932O4M) .

also i found some packages about replacing mysql with MariaDB the Mysql sibling, [here](https://gist.github.com/odan/c799417460470c3776ffa8adce57eece).

I am using Ubuntu so i think manual package upgrade should work but if not try to upgrade th xampp higher version to be safe.

---

update 
this is a link to a question about update mysql under linux, [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7).
actually i found couple of links about update mysql under xampp but on windows system so i think it is irrelevant to the topic.

Comment: i checked the highest version of xampp but it contains the same version of MariaDB !

Comment: why do not you try to update the mysql package alone ? is that a hustle in Manjaro?

Comment: that's what i wanna do but it's under xampp package so i think it's a bit difficult

Comment: @Dev.SheNNawY i have updated the answer with a link to upgrade mysql , hope this could help.

Comment: i really appreciate your concern bro, but when i searched a lot i found that this version of mysql doesn't exists in the repo. yet so i'ii wait for the next update.

Comment: no need thanks brother, i know how much it sucks on Linux system when you fill lost in an issue with no support, try another more popular linux repo than manjaro so you can find more help and more recent updates.

Comment: i think i'm gonna move to Fedora :(

Comment: great choice, you can try Debian distro also , they are awesome